# How to make these tables rewsponsive

Tags: html

I am creating a new table in wordpress.org widget section, But it is not responsive. My website name is jobstock[dot]pk. you can find two tables below the post and above the footer. please check this and help me
I have used the "div style="overflow-x: auto;"" code before table tag but it does not work there.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/pakistan-army/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Pakistan-Army-Logo.png" alt="Pakistan Army" /></a>

Pakistan
Army</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/pakistan-navy/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Pakistan-Navy-Jobs.jpg" alt="Pakistan Navy" /></a>

Pakistan
Navy</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/paf/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/PAF-Logo.png" alt="Pakistan Air Force" /></a>

Pakistan
Air Force</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/health-department/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/government-of-pakistan-logo.gif" alt="Health Department" /></a>

Health
Department</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/police-department/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Punjab-Police-logo.jpg" alt="Police Department" /></a>

Police
Department</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/district-and-session-judge/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/District-And-Session-Judge-Court-logo.jpg" alt="District and Session Court" /></a>

District And
Session Court</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/education-department/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/government-of-pakistan-logo.gif" alt="Education Department" /></a>

Education
Department</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/livestock-department/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Livestock-logo-punjab.png" alt="Livestock Department" /></a>

Livestock
Department</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/nts/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/NTS-Logo.jpg" alt="NTS" /></a>

NTS</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/paec/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/PAEC-Logo.png" alt="PAEC" /></a>

PAEC</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/fpsc/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/FPSC-Logo.png" alt="FPSC" /></a>

FPSC</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/ppsc/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/PPSC-Logo.jpg" alt="PPSC" /></a>

PPSC</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/bpsc/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/BPSC-Logo.jpg" alt="BPSC" /></a>

BPSC</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/kppsc/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/KPPSC-Logo.jpg" alt="KPPSC" /></a>

KPPSC</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/spsc/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/SPSC-Logo.jpg" alt="SPSC" /></a>

SPSC</td>
<td><a href="https://www.jobstock.pk/department/fwo/"><img src="https://www.jobstock.pk/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/FWO-Logo.jpg" alt="FWO" /></a>

FWO</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

but this is not looking responsive

Comment: Don't use table for responsive layout, try `float` typography.

Comment: is there any link to learn float typography?

Comment: I am a beginner so i want to learn complete tutorial.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float See if this helps.

Comment: @Chaska I'd put that way clearer. Tables were **never** intended to be used as layouts. They were mistakenly used as such. There are multiple layout types like: flexbox, css-grid and so on. Just google any of those or even google `responsive web design`. Maybe you should read something basic about it like [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/) google blog. Here is a good read to [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). And here is a good read to [CSS-Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)